# How to execute non-blocking statements in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, web

I'd like to execute a code (`JavaScript`, web) in the background that is non-blocking for the user. In other words, I want to call a function, but I don't want the following lines to wait for the call to finish, as it may last a while (and it not necessary for the rest of the program).

Maybe something like this:

```js
function someBigFunctionIDontWantToWaitFor() {
  let i = 0;
  while (i < 100000000) {
    i++;
  }
  console.log("i =", i);
}

console.log("before call");
someBigFunctionIDontWantToWaitFor();
console.log("after call");
```

Obviously, in the console, I've this:

```
before call
100000000
after call
```

I'd like to have the following result:

```
before call
after call
100000000
```

Because `someBigFunctionIDontWantToWaitFor` takes time and the `console.log("after call")` doesn't want to wait.

Is this possible? Does it make sense?

Thank you

Comment: quickest way is doing setTimeout(() => someBigFunctionIDontWantToWaitFor(), 0);

Comment: except that still will block execution while it is running - so don't think this is a cure for code that is so intensive it blocks the browser

Comment: The proper way would be to use Web Worker for browser and Worker Threads in nodejs

Answer (score -1):

You can put the function in a then block of a Promise.

```
async function someBigFunctionIDontWantToWaitFor() {
        let i = 0;
        while (i < 100000) {
            i++;
        }
        console.log("i =", i);
  }
  
  console.log("before call");
  Promise.resolve(undefined).then(someBigFunctionIDontWantToWaitFor)
  console.log("after call");
```